# How can capture 8 numbers and 1 letter

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Sorry any help?
i want capture numbers in integer and a last letter in a string, when i wrote something like this in editText:

48392312H

i need two variables
int = 48392312;
String = "H";

any help?
thanks in advance people.

Comment: What have you done so far? As a hint: use Substring to get your variables and then convert the one into an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only the last character is always the letter, then you can do the following:

```
int number = Integer.valueOf(editTextString.substring(0, editTextString.length() - 1));
String letter = editTextString.substring(editTextString.length() - 1);
// However you should consider getting a letter as a character:
char letterChar = editTextString.charAt(editTextString.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the string you get from your EditText and then use http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char) function to determine whether or not it's a digit or a character.

Then simply add the digits to one string and the characters to another string as you go through the original string, and then parse them at the end.

That'll leave you with two variables, one with all the digits, and one with all the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String str = "48392312H";
String chars = str.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");

int digits = Integer.parseInt(str.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String s="48392312H";
    String lastCharacter=String.valueOf(s.charAt(s.length()-1));
    System.out.println(lastCharacter);
    int number=Integer.valueOf( s.replaceAll("\\D+",""));
    System.out.println(number);
```

1) Capture the input as String.
2) Get the last character of the input.
3) Replace all the characters in input with blank which are other than digits.
4) Convert the result of step 3 into Integer.